# Dual Boot - unable to access bootmanager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm new to linux and trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 alongside with Windows 10 (single-HDD Toshiba, Win 8 was pre-installed)

There were no issues during install but I'm not able to load into Ubuntu (or see any bootmanager menu at all). After trying several suggestions, I'm now able to boot Ubuntu via grub only if I hibernated from Windows or if the laptop wakes up from a complete discharge.
Booting after shut down/restart from either OS directly boots Windows without any boot manager.

The BIOS/UEFI settings only list an option to alter device boot order; no option to choose boot manager or which partition within the (only) HDD.

Things I've tried:
--Disabled fast-boot & secure-boot
--Reinstalled Ubuntu after wiping its partition
--`boot-repair` ([pastebin here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23100522/))
--`bcdedit /enum` lists only Windows 10. Setting the path to `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` (as suggested by boot-repair) did not change anything.
--Tried `grub-install` from a live-USB, which gave an error related to blocklists (see comment thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817773/dual-boot-cant-boot-into-ubuntu))

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: I'm new to this so I'd appreciate if you could maybe give more specific pointers to where I'm supposed to look...

Comment: Using Boot-Repair's advanced mode tick/check the 'Use the standard EFI file' in advanced options. That copies shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi for a hard drive boot entry. It does not look like current hard drive entry is for UEFI, so you may need an UEFI entry for that. `sudo efibootmgr -c -g -d /dev/sdX -p Y -w -L "UEFI hard drive" -l '\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi' `
sdX is drive, Y is efi partition

Comment: It looks like your firmware may be defective; oldfred's suggestion will probably get it working. Upgrading the firmware (if an update is available) might also help, but that's a long shot, in practice.